# Bundle download limit?

Tags: open-policy-agent

encountering a bit of an issue that I would need to find a work around for.
OPA Engine version is 0.23.2 and I am trying to download a bundle, but I am getting the following error message "Bundle download failed: bundle exceeded max size (1073741824 bytes)"

Answer (score 0):

The 1GB limit is hard coded (as of now) https://github.com/open-policy-agent/opa/blob/63560e0d1e767a8c973bfa217d3c734adea6d5f7/bundle/bundle.go#L42

Keep in mind that 1GB of gzipped json data is likely to use a significant amount of memory when uncompressed *and* loaded into memory. To give some context on why that limit is there... Rule of thumb is that its something like 20x from raw JSON -> golang/opa data structures in memory, and the gzip compression varies more but I think a 5:1 ratio is pretty reasonable. Napkin math on that works out to like 100GB of memory for OPA to load a 1GB bundle (1*5*20). It is unlikely that most OPA use-cases would be able/want to have that happen, hence the error.

EDIT: That 1GB limit turns out to *not* be for the compressed bundle size but instead for the uncompressed JSON files. So the memory expansion isn't as big of a ceiling (however the example above still hold true for a 1GB *compressed* sized bundle)

I would recommend filing an issue, it seems like we could probably expose a config option to increase the limit for use-cases where the memory usage is acceptable (lower ratio for gzip, less overhead on the structures, etc.. depends on the JSON data)

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear so to clarify, the bundle.tar.gz is ~98MB and its the data.json inside that is ~958MB. Does that change the numbers you mentioned above? Because 100GB seems like a very large amount.

Comment: We were able to get data in the bundle below the 1GB mark, so the error above isn't *currently* an issue, but the memory consumption is what I'm more curious about now.

Comment: Ahh ok, sorry, one thing to clarify about my original response. I incorrectly thought that was the gzipped bundle size _not_ the uncompressed JSON file size.

If I'm understanding the code where it is being used that limit is actually on a per-file basis for the JSON. So you are only concerned about the raw json -> golang/opa structure cost in memory which is (rule of thumb) something like 20x.

Comment: Ok thanks Patrick that helps me understand it better. To clarify one more thing then, BundleLimitBytes refers not to the bundle.tar.gz size itself but rather the size of the tar.gz contents? I have not had a chance to look at the bundle.go extensively, so does that mean the contents collectively cannot exceed 1GiB or no single file can exceed that amount?